# Discuss the strong and weak convergence of $B=\{u\in W_0^{1,2}(0,1):||u'||_{L^2}\le1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Consider a sequence $\{u_n\}\subset B$. Since it does exist a constant $C$ ($=1$) such that $||u_n'||_{L^2}\le C\ \forall n\ $ and such that $|u_n(0)|\le C$
$\Big(u_n(0)=u_n(1)=0 \text{ by the definition of the set} \Big)$, then by weak compactness theorem in $W^{1,p}$ spaces, there exists $\bar{u}\in W_0^{1,2}$ and a subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\}$ such that $u_{n_k}\to\bar{u}$ uniformly, and $u_{n_k}'\rightharpoonup \bar{u}'$ weakly in $L^2$ as $k$ goes to infinity. So $B$ is weakly compact.

How to discuss the strong convergence of $B$? The Rellich theorem says that every bounded sequence in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ bounded and regular $n$-dimensional domain, has a subsequence converging strongly in $L^s(\Omega)$, with $s<\frac{np}{n-p}$. But it is not possibile to use this result since in this exercise $n=1$.

Another thing to consider is that by the Poincare inequality, it follows that also $u$ is $L^2$-bounded (by the same constant $C$). And so the Sobolev norm of $u$, which is equal to the $L^2$ norm of $u$ plus the $L^2$ norm of $u'$, is bounded. Can we conclude something with this fact? Hints are also welcome

Comment: Thanks, could you explain more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Poincaré inequality, the set $B$ is bounded in $W^{1,2}_0$. Since the embedding $W^{1,2}_0\to L^2$ is compact (this is known as Rellich or Kondrachov embedding theorem), the set $B$ is strongly (and thus also weakly) precompact in $L^2$.

It remains to show that $B$ is weakly closed in $L^2$. Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence in $B$ converging weakly to $u$ in $L^2$. Since $B$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ converging weakly in $W^{1,2}_0$, and since weak convergence in $W^{1,2}_0$ implies weak convergence in $L^2$, the weak limit in $W^{1,2}_0$ is actually $u$. Thus $u\in W^{1,2}_0$ and $\|u'\|_2\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\|u_n'\|_2\leq 1$.

In the case $n=1$ one actually gets a stronger compactness property. This is because $W^{1,2}_0(0,1)$ embeds continuously into the Hölder space $C^{0,1/2}([0,1])$, and by Arzela-Ascoli, the embedding $C^{0,1/2}([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ is compact. Hence $B$ is compact in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Question 1. I read the Rellich/Kondrachov embedding theorem, and it says that $W^{1,p}$ is compactly embedded in $L^q$ for $1\le q \le np/(n-p)$. You said that $W_0^{1,2}$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$, but in our case $n=1$ and $p=2$, so $np/(n-p))=-2$. Since it is negative what happens? Question 2: how do you get that $\alpha=1/2$ for the continuous embedding of $W$ in $C$? Thank you again

Comment: About question 2, is it because of this? https://i.imgur.com/rgs8mFt.png
in our case $N=1$ and $p=2$ so $0 \le \lambda \le 1/2$ and you picked $\lambda=1/2$?

Comment: Yes, that's the result I used. By the way, I don't think it is advisable to treat all these embedding theorems as black boxes. It is a little long for an answer, but in the one-dimensional case, everything can be verified quite easily by hand. It's essentially only integration by parts and Hölder's inequality. I recommend that as exercise.